# Jmeter response time is higher than manual execution time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, response-time

There is difference I see in the Jmeter response time versus manually captured response time.
I record the execution using blazemeter and make necessary token updates to execute the scripts. 
Result is as below :

1. Launch : Jmeter-8000ms : Manual-2000ms
2. Login : Jmeter-10000ms : Manual-3000ms
3. Search : Jmeter-8000ms : Manual-1000ms
4. Logout : Jmeter-4000ms : Manual- 500ms

Why is Jmeter adding extra time when compared to the browser execution? 
How can I mimic and get the response time as that of manual execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [cleaning your browsing history](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000510.htm), especially [browser cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), it might be the case your application relies on "heavy" content like large images or pieces of JavaScript code. JMeter simulates a "clean" session each time and browser retrieves some content from disk or memory cache. Also consider adding [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. If you recorded calls to embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts) - remove these HTTP Request samplers and instead instruct JMeter to download them in parallel using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

   [image]
3. If your application is based on [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) technology these requests are also executed in parallel by real browsers. JMeter cannot parse JavaScript so if you recorded AJAX-driven requests you need to execute them in parallel in order to produce the same network footprint as real browser does. It can be achieved using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) which can overcome JMeter's Thread Groups limitations and execute its children at the same time

Comment: According to the suggestions i have performed point 1 and 2. Cleared the cache and recorded the flow again. Selected the Embedded Resources checkbox in HTTP Request but found no difference in the response time. For the last point, yes the request could be executed in parallel from browser but the call made is one HTTP Request which would inturn calls few sub request. How do we handle such conditions?